# Elasticsearch query to find if location match preference value of morning, afternoon, evening or anytime

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation

I have the below data in documents in Elasticsearch.

```
{
   "notificationTimePreference": "morning", // could be afternoon, evening, or anytime
   "ipLocation":{
      "zip":"XXXX",
      "regionCode":"ENG",
      "city":"Morden",
      "countryCode":"GB",
      "regionName":"England",
      "coordinates":{
         "lon":-0.1111111111111,
         "lat":51.2222222222222
      },
      "countryName":"United Kingdom",
      "continentName":"Europe",
      "continentCode":"EU"
   }
}
```

I want to retrieve all the documents that are matching `notificationTimePreference` based on the `ipLocation` data.

If I retrieve each document I could do this with the C# code below but in millions of documents that would kill compute processing time.

```
private NotificationTimePreference FindPartOfDay(IpLocation location)
{
    var Coordinates = new GeoCoordinate(
        location.Coordinates.Lat,
        location.Coordinates.Lon);

    var closestZoneId = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
        .Where(x => x.CountryCode == location.CountryCode)
        .Select(x => new {x.ZoneId, Coordinates = new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude)})
        .OrderBy(x => GetDistanceTo(x.Coordinates, Coordinates))
        .Select(x => x.ZoneId)
        .First();

    var LocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(
        DateTime.UtcNow,
        TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(closestZoneId)
    );

    var partsOfTheDay = new[]
    {
        NotificationTimePreference.Evening,
        NotificationTimePreference.Morning,
        NotificationTimePreference.Afternoon,
        NotificationTimePreference.Evening
    };

    return partsOfTheDay[LocalTime.Hour % 20 / 6 | 0];
}

private static double GetDistanceTo(GeoCoordinate coord, GeoCoordinate to)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(coord.Latitude) || double.IsNaN(coord.Longitude) || double.IsNaN(to.Latitude) ||
        double.IsNaN(to.Longitude))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("wrong arguments");
    }

    var latitude = coord.Latitude * 0.0174532925199433;
    var longitude = coord.Longitude * 0.0174532925199433;
    var num = to.Latitude * 0.0174532925199433;
    var longitude1 = to.Longitude * 0.0174532925199433;
    var num1 = longitude1 - longitude;
    var num2 = num - latitude;
    var num3 = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num2 / 2), 2) +
               Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(num) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(num1 / 2), 2);
    var num4 = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(num3), Math.Sqrt(1 - num3));
    var num5 = 6376500 * num4;
    return num5;
}
```

Advanced ES queries are not my cup of tea and not sure how to approach this one!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The c# code does help but it's not sufficient. Do you want to double check your documents and make sure the preference is stored correctly (and update them if needed)? Also, can you expound on `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource`? Is it a c# collection of timezones?

Comment: @JoeSorocin actually trying to find the documents where the region matches the notification time preference using the server UTC time; I should update the description a bit if that makes more sense. The C# code does that exactly if you fetch the documents and loop through each to determine the NotificationTimePreference.

Comment: About https://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html